# Put trivariate PDF in terms of bivariate PDFs

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let there be the random variables $X$, $Y$, and $Z$. Let all the bivariate PDFs $f_{X, Y}$, $f_{X, Z}$, and $f_{Y, Z}$ be known.

Can we write the unknown trivariate PDF $f_{X, Y, Z}$ in terms of the known bivariate PDFs?

Comment: No.  Knowing the pairwise distributions between the variables is not sufficient to know the mutual distribution.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that. Might you please provide an informal proof by contradiction with some example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example, obtained by tweaking a 2D counterexample: Let $(X,Y,Z)$ be such that
$$
f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)=
\begin{cases}
2 \phi(x)\phi(y)\phi(z) & xyz>0\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
where $\phi$ is the standard 1D Gaussian pdf.  Then the bivariates $f_{X,Y}, f_{Y,Z}, f_{Z,X}$ are all standard 2D Gaussians, but of course $(X,Y,Z)$ is not Gaussian.  Now both the standard 3D Gaussian and this $f$ give the same distribution of bivariates.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x,y,z)=1$ when $x,y,z\in [0,1]$, and be zero otherwise. Then $f_{X,Y}$ is uniform on the unit square, and same for $f_{X,Z}$ and $f_{Y,Z}$. On the other hand, let
$$
g(x,y,z)=1+\sin(2\pi (x+y+z)) \hspace{1cm}\text{for }x,y,z\in [0,1]
$$
Then $g_{X,Y},g_{X,Z}$ and $g_{Y,Z}$ are also uniform on the unit square.